# Microsoft Teams Meeting Link does not add me to into room

Tags: microsoft-teams

I received a Microsoft Teams meeting link, which does not work as expected: add me into the meeting room.

1. Connecting from desktop. Teams application installed.
2. Same result for Chrome or Edge
3. Click the meeting link.
4. Teams, but doesn't connect to the meeting.
5. The "Join" button creates a new meeting.

Very frustrating... the call was for an interview.

Can anyone shed any light on why the meeting link did not put me into the meeting?

Comment: Hello, Have you tried  signing out of your account and logging back?
It seems like product issue, could you please raise product related queries to [Microsoft teams product channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT the product channels say to post here on SO. Also, no way to join using a meeting ID with Teams. This product does not appear to support meetings external to an organization.